# Which of these is the best practice for accessing a variable in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have an object, and within that object I've defined a variable, which of these methods would be considered 'best' for accessing the variable?

**Method One**

Using a getter function

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.the_variable = 21 * 2

    def get_the_variable(self):
        return self.the_variable

if __name__ == "__main__"
    a = MyClass()
    print(a.get_the_variable())
```

**Method Two**

Using the `@property` decorator

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self._the_variable = 21 * 2

    @property
    def the_variable(self):
        return self._the_variable

if __name__ == "__main__"
    a = MyClass()
    print(a.the_variable)
```

**Method Three**

Simply accessing it directly

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.the_variable = 21 * 2

if __name__ == "__main__"
    a = MyClass()
    print(a.the_variable)
```

Are any of these methods more pythonic than the others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Method 3 is the standard pythonic way to start.  If you need additional logic, filtering or some other behavior for the attribute you can always go back and add a method for the attribute and use the @property decorator at a later time.  That's the beauty of python, start with something simple that works.  If you later need finer control over the attribute you can create the property and not have to update/change any of the client code that uses the attribute.  The client code will not know the difference between accessing the attribute directly vs calling a method and as a result does not have to change.

This ideology is confirmed via [PEP 549](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0549/)

> Python's descriptor protocol guides programmers towards elegant API design. If your class supports a data-like member, and you might someday need to run code when changing the member's value, you're encouraged to simply declare it as a simple data member of the class for now. If in the future you do need to run code, you can change it to a "property", and happily the API doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I do believe that your reasoning was probably what the original developer had in mind when implementing the `@property` method; to extend the functionality of `foo.bar` method of accessing a class attribute. Could you perhaps cite a PEP or another article that corroborates that Method 3 is the pythonic way?

Comment: I've added a quote from PEP 549 that reiterates the concept

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not easy to answer since it's based on the program.

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self):
      self.the_variable = 21 * 2

  def get_the_variable(self):
      return self.the_variable
```

But if you want to pass a class attirubete to some variable, I think it's better to use `getter-setter`, since it is more readable and understandable. Because you are basically telling I ask this value. For example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  a = MyClass()

  modified_variable = a.get_the_variable() * 2
```

In contrary, if you are just using that class attribute, third option `a.the_variable` is better.

```
if a.get_the_variable() == 42:
   # do something
else:
   # do something
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I think that directly accessing the attribute (3rd method) is the same as using getter-setter in terms of readability, because both ways basically say that you are asking this value.